# Trying to find two random nodes and swap them in a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, shuffle, doubly-linked-list

This program is basically just suppose to shuffle a deck of cards. The cards are stored in a doubly linked list, so 52 nodes. I'm getting a read access error in the getNode function, but I'm pretty sure my loop is correct, so I think the error is stemming from somewhere else. Maybe the swap function. My first step is getting pointers to the nodes that I'm trying to swap.

So I made a function, and I'm pretty sure it's right, except I'm wondering if I should be returning *traverseP instead of just traverseP. I don't think so, because I want to return a pointer to the node, not the value inside the node.

```
template<class T>
typename ReorderableList<T>::Node *ReorderableList<T>::getNode(int i) const
{
    int count = 0;
    for (Node *traverseP = firstP; traverseP != NULL; traverseP = traverseP->nextP) {
        if (count == i)
            return traverseP;
        count++;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Next I made a swap function that take two ints, they represent the values I'm passing into the getNode function

```
    template<class T>
    void ReorderableList<T>::swap(int i, int j)
    {
        // Get pointers to ith and jth nodes.
        Node *iPtr = getNode(i);
        Node *jPtr = getNode(j);

        //create temp Node and store the pointers
        Node *temp = new Node;
        temp = iPtr->prevP;
        temp = iPtr->nextP;

        //adjust the iPtr next/prev pointers
        iPtr->prevP = jPtr->prevP;
        iPtr->nextP = jPtr->nextP;

        //adjust the jPtr next/prev pointers
        jPtr->prevP = temp->prevP;
        jPtr->nextP = temp->prevP;

        //I'm a little unclear on these lines. I think they're checking if
        //iPtr and jPtr have null pointers. I've tried making them equal jPtr and 
        //iPtr and that strangly didn't make any difference.
        if (iPtr->prevP)
            iPtr->prevP->nextP = jPtr;
        if (iPtr->nextP)
            iPtr->nextP->prevP = jPtr;

        if (jPtr->prevP)
            jPtr->prevP->nextP = iPtr;
        if (jPtr->nextP)
            jPtr->nextP->prevP = iPtr;

        delete temp;
    }
```

This is the shuffle function where this whole shabang kicks off

```
template<class T>
void randomShuffle(ReorderableList<T> &list, int n)
{
    int randNum = 0;    
    for (int i = n-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        randNum = (rand() & (i + 1));
        if (randNum > i)
            std::swap(randNum, i);

        list.swap(randNum, i);
    }
}
```

I've checked a couple different resources for the swap function and found two that both claimed they were correct, but they looked different to me.
[Resource 1](https://ideone.com/wsd3OX)
[Resource 2](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/102181/)

Comment: Provide a [mcve] to reproduce the error please.

Comment: Why are you using `randNum = (rand() & (i + 1));` instead of `randNum = (rand() % n);`?

Comment: `jPtr->nextP = temp->prevP;` is wrong.

Comment: @RSahu because I don't want to generate a number between 1-52 everytime. The first iteration should, but then the second iteration should generate a random number between 1-51 etc..

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Just that line or both jPtr->nextP and jPtr->prevP lines?

Comment: @Sean, I think you need the random numbers to be `0-51`, `0-50`, etc.?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm yeah, that's what i meant. but that should be what i-1 gives me since the loop initializes at 51 and then decrements

Comment: Did you mean `rand() % (i+1)` ?

Comment: You might consider, instead of swapping the nodes themselves (and dealing with the relinking), just swapping the Nodes' data.

Comment: Even if you decide to swap the nodes themselves, there is no need to allocate any new nodes at all, just unlink the two nodes and re-link them at the opposite locations. `Node *temp = new Node; temp = iPtr->prevP;` is a memory leak, and `temp = iPtr->prevP; temp = iPtr->nextP;` is trying to track two separate pointers using a single variable, so `jPtr->prevP = temp->prevP; jPtr->nextP = temp->prevP;` doesn't set one of the nodes correctly.

Comment: @PhilM yup...wasn't the cause of the problem, but I'm sure it would have screwed something up. I've considered just swapping the data, but I know I've done this before and it's bothering me now

Comment: @RemyLebeau nice name. I see what you're saying I think about using temp to track two pointers so I'm changing to 'temp = iPtr->prevP; iPtr->prevP = jPtr->prevP; jPtr->prevP = temp; temp = iPtr->nextP; iPtr->nextP = jPtr->nextP; jPtr->nextP = temp;' Maybe that'll fix it, but doesn't 'delete temp;' at the end prevent the memory leak?

Comment: @Sean "*doesn't 'delete temp;' at the end prevent the memory leak?*" - no, because it is not freeing the same `Node` that was `new`'ed, because `temp` is reassigned after `new` to point at a different `Node`

Comment: @Remy ahhhh... thanks for the tip